# Use firebase ML Kit to identify species of animals

Tags: android-studio, google-mlkit

I Have being played around with google firebase ML KIT to identify some objects from images taken by the phone camera.

But I only was able to get some text telling if it is an animal, TV, electrical device, and soon.

What i want to die is something like Google lens, where I can take a picture and it identifies the species of the animal.

Is it possible with the firebase ML KIT? If not what else can I use to achieve this?

[image]

This are images from google lens but I would like to do something like this but more specific. Only for marine animals

Answer (score 0):

you will need a custom model to classifier detailed species. ML Kit sdk supports a tflite model being passed in by developers to do classifications. See the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/custom-models/android) here.